# How do I change the MySQL data directory?

Tags: mysql

How do I change the MySQL data directory with Mysqld command in cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Change the directive in the /etc/my.cnf file

```
datadir = /rddata/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

specifies the --datadir=[path] parameter

Answer (score 0):

u should copy all data to target folder. and then modify the `/etc/my.cnf`

`[mysqld]`
`datadir= {your data folder path}`

and then restart your mysql .that will be ok